# How do I make the URL for my webpage work if the last part of the path is a variable?

Tags: javascript, java, html, url, path

I have written a REST api in Java and a turn based online client game that utilizes the api. When a player creates a new game instance, other players can join given the game id via a URL.

So say Player1 creates a new game instance from the page [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) and an invite URL is generated that looks like so [www.mysite.com/{id}](http://www.mysite.com/%7Bid%7D).

Instead of actually going to that invalid URL since no page is associated with it, How do I make it so that Player 2 will just go to the default page instead so that I can later grab the ID path variable and handle the joining process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

### One: use a query parameter

Simply instead of `/{id}` use `?id={id}`.

This way you can get the parameter from javascript and the webserver knows what to do.

### Two: setup webserver to serve the same file by pattern

This will depend on the webserver, but basically what you are doing is saying if request url is of a specific pattern serve that file.

For apache that would look something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: The query parameter idea worked. Thank you. Going to go with that one for now as I learn more about web development/full stack